# example of equi-depth histograms in databases?

Tags: database

I am unable to understand the role equi-depth histograms play in query optimization. Can someone please give me some pointers to good resources or could anyone explain. I have read a few research papers but still I could not convince my for the need and use of equi-depth histograms. So, can someone please explain equi-depth histograms with an example.

Also can we merge the buckets of the histograms so that the histogram becomes small enough and fits in 1 page on disk?

Also what are bucket boundaries in equi-depth histograms?

Comment: You might not have effective tags for this question. Your question has to do with the internals of the query optimizer, which database designers usually treat as a black box. Your existing tags will attract the attention of database designers like me, but probably won't attract the attention of, say, C or C++ programmers who write the optimizer.

Comment: @Catcall: You mean the attention of that one programmer that is writing optimizers and also reading SO? ;)

Comment: You'd be surprised who's on SO. But I was thinking more along the lines of university students or open source contributors who might know more about this than I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not an expert on database internals, so this is a general, not a specific answer.

Query compilers convert the query, usually given in SQL, to a plan for obtaining the result.  Plans consist of low level "instructions" to the database engine: scan table T looking for value V in column C; use index X on table T to locate value V; etc.

Query optimization is about the compiler deciding which of a (potentially huge) set of alternative query plans have minimum cost. Costs include wall clock time, IO bandwidth, intermediate result storage space, CPU time, etc.  Conceptually, the optimizer is searching the alternative plan space, evaluating the cost of each to guide the search, ultimately choosing the cheapest it can find.

The costs mentioned above depend on estimates of how many records will be read and/or written, whether the records can be located by indexes, what columns of those records will be used, and the size of the data and/or how many disk pages they occupy.

These quantities in turn often depend on the exact data values stored in the tables. Consider for example `select * from data where pay > 100` where `pay` is an indexed column. If the pay column has no values over 100, then the query is extremely cheap.  A single probe of the index answers it. Conversely the result set could contain the entire table.

This is where histograms help.  (Equi-depth histograms are just one way of maintaining histograms.)  In the preceeding query a histogram will in O(1) time provide an estimate of the fraction of rows that will be produced by the query without knowing exactly what those rows will contain.

In effect, the optimizer is "executing" the query on an abstraction of the data.  The histogram is that abstraction.  (Others are possible.)  The histogram is useful for estimating costs and result sizes for query plan operations: join result size and page hits during mass insertions and deletions (which may lead to the generation of a temporary index), for example.

For a simple inner join example, suppose we know how integer-valued join columns of two tables are distributed:

```
Bins (25% each)
Table A                    Table B
0-100                      151-300 
101-150                    301-500  
151-175                    601-700
176-300                    1001-1100
```

It's easy to see that 50% of Table A and 25% of Table B reflect the possible participation.  If these are unique-valued columns, then a useful join size estimate is max(.5 * |A|, .25 * |B|).  This is a very simple example.  In many (most?) cases, the analysis requires much more mathematical sophistication.  For joins, it's usual to compute an estimated histogram of the results by "joining" the histograms of the operands. This is what makes the literature so diverse, complicated, and interesting.

PhD dissertations often have surveys that cover big bodies of technical literature like this in a concise form that isn't too difficult to read.  (After all, the candidate is trying to convince a committee he/she knows how to do a literature search.)  [Here](http://cs.txstate.edu/~hn12/all.pdf) is one such example.

Comment: Good answer. Interesting would be an answer to the question: "why equi-depth histograms", rather than just plain equi-width histograms? My guess: Equi-depth histograms are more space-efficient when there are many distinct values, as the number of bins is fixed and independent of the number of distinct values. If otoh there aren't that many distinct values, equi-width would consume less space.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Exactly.  Equidepth provides a natural way for the data structure to conform to the structure of the data it holds. For any fixed amount of space, it provides the best possible fidelity.